# Binomial distribution confusion

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Whats the difference between  pbinom(2074000, 4247000, 0.5) and  pbinom(2074, 4247, 0.5), why do they give differing values when the proportions are same?

Comment: Proportions between what and what? Is this R? What do the arguments mean, what does this function output? You are definitely not the only one who is confused

Comment: I suppose you mean the R function `pbinom`: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251046/what-is-the-difference-between-qbinom-and-pbinom-in-r

Comment: This is an example of why we don't like questions that are so poorly explained. You expect people to know what pbinom is, but it is a not-so-obvious fact that it is the cumulative distribution function of a binomial distribution. You already have people answering as if it were the probability mass function of the binomial, and that is your fault for not explaining what you are talking about.

Comment: I think I got my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you're just working on a command calculation for the probability density function of the binomial distribution, it's simple to answer this just because :

$$\binom{4247000}{2074000} \neq \binom{4247}{2074}$$

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a question of equal proportions it's a question of the probability of getting an exact proportion out of a number of trials.

The probability of getting $1$ head out of two coin tosses is $\frac{1}{2}$. That is $2$ out of $4$ possible outcomes HH, HT, TH, HH.

Which is not the same as getting $2$ heads out of four coin tosses which is  $\frac{3}{8}$ That is, $6$ out of $16$ possible outcomes HHHH, HHHT, HHTH, HTHH, THHH, HHTT, HTHT, HTTH, THHT, THTH, TTHH, HTTT, THTT, TTHT, TTTH, TTTT.

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I use the fact that `pbinom` is defined as a cumulative distribution rather than a probability mass function. If it were a probability mass function the effect would be much more dramatic.

---

When you multiply the number of trials by $1000,$ the range of possible outputs of the binomial distribution also grows by a factor of $1000,$ and so does the variance of the distribution--but the standard deviation is only the square root of the variance.

In short, the shape of the binomial distribution for $4247000$ trials is not just like the distribution for $4274$ trials stretched laterally by a factor of $1000.$
The two *extremes* of the distribution are $1000$ times as far from the mean,
but the probable outcomes are not that much further from the mean;
you'll find a much higher probability of being within $\pm1\%$ of the mean value.
To put it another way, the outcome $2047000$ is many more standard deviations below the mean of $4247000$ trials than the outcome $2047$ is below the mean of $4247$ trials.